# Lambda function as handler for redirect URI generates ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, callback, fastapi

I have a Fast API that is hosted in a AWS Lambda function (by wrapping is with Magnum). One of the routes of this API serves as the redirect URI for an Admin Consent on Azure AD.

When the Admin provides consent the route is triggered correctly and succeeds without errors (in the logs of the lambda function).

Nevertheless, in the browser once the user is redirected I am presented with a ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED error. This in turn triggers the lambda function again and again and again.

**Does someone have any idea on why using a Lambda handler as redirect URI seems not to be working?**

Side note: The error has to be due to the redirect itself as it even bugs out when I just return immediately without any processing.

Comment: "Does someone have any idea on why using a Lambda handler as redirect URI seems not to be working" can you elaborate more on this? What is your redirect code? Can you share the code?

Comment: I have an App registration in my Azure AD that needs consent of an administrator of another tenant to retrieve the Users from within the Azure AD. This is done by providing the (other tennant's) administrator with a "Consent URL". When the user visits this URL he logs in into Azure and gives consent to the required permissions for my application.

Once the consent is given, the redirect URI is called and thus triggers my aws Lambda.